# How to determine logfile folder on Linux?

Tags: linux, posix, logfiles

I want to write a logfile of activities of my program. Does it always go to `/var/log/` or `/var/log/appname/` if multiple files are written? Is there a common environment variable like `$LOGDIR`? What would be the POSIX way to do that? Also, what is the expected log filename on *nix? Something like `{name}.{date}.{pid}.log`?

Comment: The only thing POSIX specifies is how logs are sent: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/syslog.html Handling log entries is a task of syslog daemon (syslogd, syslog-ng, rsyslog, systemd-journald) which has specific configuration on where and how put logs.

Comment: Except for applications that log to files rather than to syslog (e.g., Apache)...

Comment: @myaut Then the acutal way to do it is not writing a logfile at all but use syslog?!

Comment: @CodeClown, are you trying to log something or are you trying to parse some application's logs?

Comment: @myaut I am trying to log something.

Comment: @CodeClown, than `syslog` routines are a good start, if you do not have specific logging requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it always go to /var/log/ or /var/log/appname/ if multiple files are written?

Absolutely not.  Logs may not even be stored on the local system (they may be shipped off to a remote collector using any of a variety of technologies).

> Is there a common environment variable like $LOGDIR? What would be the POSIX way to do that?

Again, no such luck.  For applications that log to `syslog`, the configuration may be in `/etc/syslog.conf`, or `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, or even somewhere else if a different syslog server is in use.  For applications that *don't* log to syslog, it's a per-application configuration.

> Also, what is the expected log filename on *nix? Something like {name}.{date}.{pid}.log?

There is no expected log filename.  It varies from application to application.